# C++: Store & Call the function pointers in a vector of function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I've a scenario as below code. I'm trying to

1. Store the address of a C++ member function in a vector of function pointers.
2. access a C++ member function using this vector of function pointers.

I am able to add the functions, but I can't call them. The error I get is:

> error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in

```
class allFuncs {
     private:
        std::vector<void *(allFuncs::*)(int)> fp_list; // Vector of function pointers

       void func_1(int a) {
           // some code
        }

       void func_2(int a) {
           // some code
        }

        void func_3() {
           // STORING THE FUNCTION POINTER INTO The VECTOR OF FUNCTION POINTERS
           fp_list.push_back(&func_2);
           fp_list.push_back(allFuncs::func_1);      
        }

        func_4() {
          // Calling the function through the function pointer in vector
          this->*fp_list.at(0)(100);  // this does not work 
        }
}
```

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573184/vector-of-pointers-to-member-functions-with-multiple-objects-c

Comment: @NathanOliver: Updated with proper syntax for declaring vector of function pointers but I'm facing issues while calling the function pointer using the syntax: (I've updated in the code.   this->*fp_list.at(0)(100);

Comment: I believe you need another set of parentheses: `this->*(fp_list.at(0))(100);`

Comment: Tried this too actually but same error & cribbing for "error: must use '.' or '->' to call pointer-to-member function in"

Comment: OK.  I've edit the Q to make the calling syntax the actual question and reopened it.  I know the syntax is really funky, I just can't remember it.

Comment: Aha, try `(this->*fp_list.at(0))(100)`.

Comment: Awesome  (this->*fp_list.at(0))(100)   worked.  I wonder how does this outer parenthesis make a difference.

Comment: I've added an answer with an explanation for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
(this->*fp_list.at(0))(100)
```

to call the function from the vector.  When you do

```
this->*fp_list.at(0)(100)
```

The function call (the `(100)` part) is bound to `fp_list.at(0)` so basically you have

```
this->*(fp_list.at(0)(100))
```

which won't work. Adding parentheses around the function pointer access fixes that so `this->*fp_list.at(0)` becomes the function to call and then the `(100)` is used on that function.