# templated function as a parameter to another templated function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an utility function which takes two values and does something on another object if two values meet a certain criteria.

So, the utility function has to take a member function as a std:function and also sometimes as a free flowing function.

```
class A
{
    public:
    void fun(int a) {}
};

template <typename T>
bool ifSet(T a, T b, std::function<void(T)> f )
{
    if (a == b) return false;
    else return f(b);
}

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_shared<A>(new A);
    std::cout<< ifSet(10, 10, std::bind(A::fun, p, std::placeholders::_1));
```

The above code is my dummy implementation, but doesn't work. Can someone suggest me a better code ?

Comment: "_but doesn't work._" Such statement is meaningless - please explain what, **exactly**, doesn't work in such implementation.

Comment: if `f()` return `void` and `ifSet` return a `bool`, with `return f(b);` you have a problem

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131768/how-to-directly-bind-a-member-function-to-an-stdfunction-in-visual-studio-11

Comment: Rather use a lambda function instead of `std::bind()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your

`std::function<void(T)> f`

return a **void** and you use it as return for **bool** ifSet() function